# How to reset ASP.NET Startup page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've accidentaly clicked "**Set as Startup page**" on Index.aspx of ASP.NET MVC application.

Now every time I click Debug, it starts here: **http://localhost:5577/Views/Home/Index.aspx**

Which obviously gives me an error.

Can i revert the startup page back to the original **http://localhost:5577**?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Set your start URL to be blank in the project properties.

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio 2012: `Project > XXXX Properties > Web`

Comment: Clicking the 'Specific Page' radio button and clearing the textbox so that it is empty worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

project -> property pages -> Start Options -> Use Current page

Comment: This MAY work but as it suggests, it will try to run the 'Current Page' which may not be the 'original' or root page as requested by the OP. The accepted answer from @p.campbell works as required.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the start url in the web tab of project properties

Info from msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983445.aspx)